# Can't Index my Pandas Dataframe by Column

Tags: python, pandas

```
readHTML=pd.read_html(url)
#The pandas read turned back a list with some useless data
df=readHTML[11]
#Returned as data frame
```

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnggs.png)

However, I was noticing I could not index my DataFrame by columns When I did:

```
df['Trade Date']
```

I got back the error:

KeyError: 'Trade Date'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
3364
3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'Trade Date'

So I thought it was a problem with the spaces, so I tried:

```
df.rename(columns = {'Trade Date':'Trade_Date', 'Filing Date':'Filing_Date', 'Trade Type':'Trade_Type'}, inplace=True)
df.columns
```

I got the result:

Index(['X', 'Filing Date', 'Trade Date', 'Ticker', 'Insider Name', 'Title',
'Trade Type', 'Price', 'Qty', 'Owned', 'ΔOwn', 'Value', '1d', '1w',
'1m', '6m'],
dtype='object')

The fact that it came from a list might be the culprit:

```
type(df)
```

Result:

pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

> enter code here

Comment: Could you please do `print(df.columns)`? I'd guess, that you just have a typo in your column name.

Comment: `print(df.columns)` gets me:

Index(['X', 'Filing Date', 'Trade Date', 'Ticker', 'Insider Name', 'Title',
       'Trade Type', 'Price', 'Qty', 'Owned', 'ΔOwn', 'Value', '1d', '1w',
       '1m', '6m'],
      dtype='object')

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import pandas as pd  
  
# Create sample 
data = {'Trade Date': ['2020-12-01', '2020-12-02', '2020-12-03', '2020-12-04'], 'Filing Date': ['Filing Date1', 'Filing Date2', 'Filing Date3', 'Filing Date4'], 'Trade Type':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}  
  
# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# Create Index
df = df.set_index('Trade Date')
df
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I should have clarified in the title, I'm trying to change the column names to take out spaces or be able to `df['column']` without drawing the error another way. Also, I'm getting my data out of a list.

Comment: I think you should edit your question and give more context so that we can help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up naming the columns by hand:

```
df.columns=['X', 'Filing_Date', 'Trade_Date', 'Ticker', 'Insider_Name', 'Title', 'Trade_Type', 'Price', 'Qty', 'Owned', 'ΔOwn', 'Value', '1d', '1w','1m', '6m']
```